# How to write an embedded C program for adding two numbers stored in memory locations

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

Can use a pointer to access content of the memory location on embedded c.

```
int *p;
p = (int*) 0x30610000;
```

I need to write a program that add two numbers stored in memory location.

```
int *p;
int *q;
p = (int*) 0x30610000;
q = (int*) 0x30610004;
int sum=(*p)+(*q)
```

Is the above code correct?

I need understand how access a content of memory location on embedded c.

Comment: assuming that the addressing is correct , then you have p and q that points to memory locations and then  you sum their values into int sum, seems to be ok, do you see any issue with it ?

Comment: @user1153191 It depends how values are updated in memory. Probably you need `volatile int *p`. Good practice is to declare macro which evaluates value of variable, not a pointer to it. Also use explicit width if type is hardware depended, e.g. `#define P (*(volatile int32_t *)(0x30610000))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask if it is "*correct*", then in comments ask whether it is "*good practice*". They are two separate questions.  It is syntactically and semantically correct (apart from the missing semi-colon).  Whether it is good practice is context dependent and to some extent a matter of opinion.  You have provided little context to come to a view but consider:

- if these are device registers or shared memory that may change spontaneously outside of the current thread context, they should be declared `volatile`,
- if the pointers should never change they should be declared const,
- prefer initialisation over declare/assign,

```
  volatile int* const p = (volatile int* const)0x30610000u ;
```

It may be syntactically clearer to use a macro represent the value at the address such as:

```
#define p (*(volatile int*)0x30610000u)
#define q (*(volatile int*)0x30610000u)

int sum = p + q ;
```

But that may be regarded as an obfuscation.  You would normally clarify such code by naming convention - macros at conventionally capitalised, and `P` and `Q` really don't cut it w.r.t. clarity or meaningfulness.  The names should reflect the purpose or nature of the data stored

Where the values are hardware registers, the data type might explicitly match the register width, using stdint.h types.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on how the values ended up in that memory location in the first place. There are 3 different scenarios:

1. Hardware registers. See [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)
2. Values downloaded by the linker, a bootloader or similar but they lack a C language identifier (variable name).
3. Values downloaded by the linker that have a C language identifier (variable name).

In case the location is named with a variable name, you *cannot* access its absolute address like in your example. This can give all manner of problems related to optimization and pointer aliasing. In such cases you need to `volatile` qualify all access to the variable, including the original declaration, and disable strict pointer aliasing as well (gcc `-fno-strict-aliasing`). Such code is non-portable between compilers.

Otherwise, in case the location is not named, you can access it like you would with a hardware register. Follow the advise in the link above, including:

- Never use `int` in embedded systems, always use the types from `stdint.h`. Never use signed types in embedded systems unless the data is explicitly signed.
- Always `u`/`U` suffix all hex constants to avoid problems with signedness.
- Always `volatile` qualify the access, for example by using a `volatile uint32_t*` pointer.

In your specific scenario also consider variable value ranges and over/underflow of values.